# Equivalence relation with complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, relations, equivalence-relations

In $ \mathbb{C} $ we define the binary relations $ R_{j} $ , $ j=1,2,3,4. $

$ z_{1}  R_{1} z_{2} \Leftrightarrow |z_{1}| = |z_{2}| $

$ z_{1}  R_{2} z_{2} \Leftrightarrow arg(z_{1}) = arg(z_{2}) $ or $ z_{1} = z_{2} = 0 $

$ z_{1}  R_{3} z_{2} \Leftrightarrow \bar{z_{1}} = z_{2} $

$ z_{1}  R_{4} z_{2} \Leftrightarrow z_{1} = e^{i\phi}z_{2} $ , $ \phi \in \mathbb{R} $

Let X = { z | |z| = 1 }

Find $ R_{j}(\mathbb{R}),  R_{j}(\mathbb{X}), R_{j}(i),R_{j}(\mathbb{R}),R_{j}\circ R_{k},R_{j}^{-1} $

Find which relation is an equivalence relation and in that case determine it's quotient set.

What is the elegant and right way to find those sets ?
They might seem easy to guess but I am not that familiar with the demonstration.

Some answers : $ R_{1}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{C} $ , $ R_{2}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R} $ , $ R_{3}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R} $ , $ R_{4}(\mathbb{R}) $ = { $  (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2  |  b= a\tan\phi $ } , $ R_{1}(X) = X $, $ R_{2}(X) = \mathbb{C}^* $, $ R_{3}(X) = X $, $ R_{4}(X) = X $, $ R_{1}(i) = X $

And the only equivalent relations are the first 2 ( which is pretty obvious  because they are Kernels )

Comment: What’s wrong with the fourth one being an equivalence relation? Or wait is that supposed to be $e^{i\phi}$ or $e^{j\phi}$?

Comment: It's to to i-th power, redactation error it seems :s

Comment: So for $R_4$ is it the case that $|z_1|=|z_2|$ if $z_1 R_4 z_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of $R_j(S)$ (where $S$ is some subset of $\Bbb{C}$) as the image of the set $S$ under the relation $R_j$. What it means is as follows:
$$R_j(S)=\{z \in \Bbb{C}\, | \, s R_j z \,\,\text{ for some } s \in S\}$$

For example, if $S=\Bbb{R}$ and we are using relation $R_1$, then 
\begin{align*}
R_1(\Bbb{R}) & =\{z \in \Bbb{C}\, | \, s R_j z \,\,\text{ for some } s \in \Bbb{R}\}\\
& =\{z \in \Bbb{C}\, | \, |s|=|z| \,\,\text{ for some } s \in \Bbb{R}\}\\
\end{align*}
Since every complex number $z=a+ib$ has magnitude $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so we can say that the real number $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is related to $z$ via the relation $R_1$. Thus
$$R_1(\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{C}.$$

Hope you can take it from here.